# Issue with Auth Flow using react-navigation v6 in React Native. Error: Invalid hook call. Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered

Tags: javascript, react-native, authentication, react-hooks, react-navigation

I'm new to React Native and I can't figure out how to make my Auth Flow work with react-navigation v6. I have a file named AuthContext.js, which is where I declare my Context object and manage the Auth state. I suspect the issue has something to do with the way I'm exporting AuthContext and or the way I'm using AuthContext in my App.js.

[Snack Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@ernesto1034/auth-flow-error-with-react-navigation-v6)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

AuthContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import myAPI from './myAPI'

// declare AuthContext as a Context object
const AuthContext = createContext();

// reducer to manage auth state
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
  (prevState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'AUTH_ERROR':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          errorMessage: action.error,
        };
      case 'CLEAR_AUTH_ERROR':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          errorMessage: '',
        };
      case 'LOG_IN':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          isLogout: false,
          userToken: action.token,
        };
      case 'LOG_OUT':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          isLogout: true,
          userToken: null,
        };
      case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  },
  {
    isLoading: true,
    isLogout: false,
    userToken: null,
    //errorMessage: '',
  }
);

//****    fetch token action    ****//
//**********************************//
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchToken = async () => {
    let userToken;
    try {
      userToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('userToken');
    } catch (err) {
      // Restoring token failed
      console.log('Unable to fetch token.');
    }
    // After restoring token, we may need to validate it
    dispatch({ type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN', token: userToken });
  };
  fetchToken();
}, []);
//**********************************//

//**** signUp, logIn, and logOut actions   ****//
//*********************************************//
const authContext = useMemo(
  () => ({
    signUp: async ({ email, username, password }) => {
      try {
        const response = await myAPI.post('/public/auth/users', {
          email,
          username,
          password,
        });
        console.log('\n', response.status);
        console.log('\n', response.data);
        // to log the user in after signup, store the token and dispatch the LOG_IN action
        // await SecureStore.setItemAsync('userToken', response.data.access_token);
        // dispatch({ type: 'LOG_IN', token: response.data.access_token });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_ERROR', error: err.response.data.detail });
        console.log('\n', err.response.status);
        console.log('\n', err.response.data);
      }
    },
    logIn: async ({ username, password }) => {
      var qs = require('query-string');
      const config = {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      };

      try {
        const response = await myAPI.post(
          '/public/auth/users/login',
          qs.stringify({ username, password }),
          config
        );
        console.log('\n', response.status);
        await SecureStore.setItemAsync('userToken', response.data.access_token);
        dispatch({ type: 'LOG_IN', token: response.data.access_token });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_ERROR', error: err.response.data.detail });
        console.log('\n', err.response.status);
        console.log('\n', err.response.data);
      }
    },
    logOut: async () => {
      await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync('token');
      dispatch({ type: 'LOG_OUT' });
    },
    clearErrorMessage: () => dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_AUTH_ERROR' }),
  }),
  []
);
//*********************************************//

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContext;
```

App.js

```
// Import Installed Libraries
import * as React from 'react';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Ionicons, FontAwesome, Foundation } from '@expo/vector-icons';

// Import Local Files
import SignupScreen from './components/SignupScreen';
import LoginScreen from './components/LoginScreen';
import FeedScreen from './components/FeedScreen';
import SearchScreen from './components/SearchScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './components/ProfileScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './components/SettingsScreen';
import LoadingScreen from './components/LoadingScreen';
import { AuthProvider } from './components/AuthContext';

// Authentication Flow
const AuthStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const AuthFlow = () => (
  <AuthStack.Navigator>
    <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
    <AuthStack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignupScreen} />
  </AuthStack.Navigator>
);

// Feed Flow
const FeedStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const FeedFlow = () => (
  <FeedStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Feed">
    <FeedStack.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} />
  </FeedStack.Navigator>
);

// Search Flow
const SearchStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const SearchFlow = () => (
  <SearchStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Search">
    <SearchStack.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
  </SearchStack.Navigator>
);

// Profile Flow
const ProfileStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const ProfileFlow = () => (
  <ProfileStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Profile">
    <ProfileStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <ProfileStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </ProfileStack.Navigator>
);

// Bottom Tap App Flow
const AppTabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
const AppFlow = () => (
  <AppTabs.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarShowLabel: false,
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#858585',
      tabBarActiveTintColor: '#000000',
    }}>
    <AppTabs.Screen
      name="FeedFlow"
      component={FeedFlow}
      headerMode="none"
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Foundation name="home" size={25} color={color} />
        ),
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    />
    <AppTabs.Screen
      name="SearchFlow"
      component={SearchFlow}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <FontAwesome name="search" size={25} color={color} />
        ),
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    />
    <AppTabs.Screen
      name="ProfileFlow"
      component={ProfileFlow}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Ionicons name="ios-person" size={25} color={color} />
        ),
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    />
  </AppTabs.Navigator>
);

const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const RootStackFlow = () => {
  const { state } = React.useContext(authContext);

  if (state.isLoading) {
    // We haven't finished checking for the token yet
    return <LoadingScreen />;
  }

  return (
    <RootStack.Navigator>
      {state.userToken == null ? (
        // No token found, user isn't logged in
        <RootStack.Screen
          name="AuthStack"
          component={AuthFlow}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        // User is logged in
        <RootStack.Screen
          name="AppTabs"
          component={AppFlow}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
      )}
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <RootStackFlow />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "expo": "^43.0.3",
    "native-base": "^3.2.2",
    "query-string": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.2",
    "react-native-masked-text": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-switch-selector": "^2.1.4",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

[Console Log Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFS2G.png)

Comment: you are suing `Hooks` outside the function Component this will not work for you.

Comment: if you could create example of this https://snack.expo.dev/ I can help you.

Comment: Thank you! Here is a working example: https://snack.expo.dev/@ernesto1034/auth-flow-error-with-react-navigation-v6

Comment: if the answer work for you, please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:
[expo auth flow](https://snack.expo.dev/@dkouk/auth-flow-error-with-react-navigation-v6)

if you want to use the `dispatch`
for example from:

```
const LoginScreen = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

 // here you can use a function to login or something, and dispatch it.

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Login Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able to implement the changes you suggested and got my app working!